# Get default deployment storage in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, storage, connection-string

I am using cloud service classic in Azure and when I deploy to a new Azure account, I have to create a new cloud storage (which has the same name by default) using deployment wizard. Is there any way to connect to this storage (get connection string programmatically) from the service without deploying first, getting connection string from the Azure portal and pasting connection string to the service configuration file? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The storage account is used to temporarily hold the deployment package during a deployment. I do not believe it is configured as part of the cloud service and thus you cannot set it as part of the cloud service configuration.

You can easily retrieve the storage account via PowerShell `Get-AzureStorageAccount` and a blob container in the storage account via PowerShell `Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $ContainerName`

Comment: Yes, thank you, but can I execute Get-AzureStorageAccount at Azure instance? I have tried it and there is no Azure Power Shell module by default.

Comment: Why do you need to execute the PowerShell script on the instance? Why do you need the storage account?

Comment: Because I need persistent storage for service's configuration which is being set via soap interface.

Comment: Anything you need installed on the instances in a cloud service, such as the PowerShell modules, should be setup via a command line using the Task part of the .csedef. You can write a script that will install everything just set it up as a simple task with elevated permissions in the Tasks section of the .csdef.